# Is it okay if I don't accept an answer even though the answer is correct?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, etiquette

For example: I have a question that I posted before.

It didn't get much attention from other users. 
I put a bounty on my question. Many users viewed my question and someone gave me a solution. I reviewed their code.

I thought, "Hmm this is good, but maybe I will wait for another answer." I didn't accept the answer nor reward the bounty (but I did upvote their answer). A few days later, another user gave me another solution. It looks better than the previous one. "Hmm, this is good, but maybe I should wait for another answers." (I upvoted it, though).

Then about 5 answers appeared and the day came where the bounty was about to end. Finally, I choose to accept the answer that matched with my opinion of "correct".

The question is, can I do this just like that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Can I do this just like that ?

Yes.

I wish more people did that instead of selecting the first answer that kinda-probably-likely helped them.

---

In fact, it is also OK to *not* choose an answer *at all*. You shouldn't feel obliged to accept any answer.